# jQuery: checkboxes checked, conditional setup

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to set up some comditions for showing and hiding elements depending on the state of two checkboxes:

- If checkbox `A` is checked, display element with the class `.one`.
  Hide elements with class `.two`.
- If checkbox `B` is checked, display element with the class `.two`.
  Hide elements with class `.one`.
- If both are checked, display both elements.
- If none of them are checked, hide both elements.

My code is below. The checkboxes are the same except for their value.
I have trouble with the logic for checking both checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<form action="">
  <div class="inputfield">
    <label for="">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="A" />
    <label for="">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="B" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="one">Results for A</div>
<div class="one">Results for A</div>
<div class="two">Results for B</div>
```

Js:

```
var a = $(".one");
var b = $(".two");
a.hide();
b.hide();

$(".inputfield input[name='xyz']").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (this.checked) {
    //console.log(value);
    if (value == 'A') {
      a.show();
      b.hide();
    }
    if (value == 'B') {
      a.hide();
      b.show();
    }
    if (value == 'A' && value == 'B') {
      a.show();
      b.show();
    }
  } else {
    a.hide();
    b.hide();
  }
});
```

**[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nmrrz6ba/).**

Comment: You can not give the same name for different inputs, because you will get exactly this trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `toggle()` and `is(':checked')`. You can use attribute selector to select each input by value attribute and then toggle `one` and `two` div's

```js
var a = $(".one");
var b = $(".two");
a.hide();
b.hide();

$(".inputfield input[name='xyz']").change(function() {
  a.toggle($('input[value="A"]').is(':checked'))
  b.toggle($('input[value="B"]').is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="inputfield">
    <label for="">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="A" />
    <label for="">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="B" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="one">Results for A</div>
<div class="one">Results for A</div>
<div class="two">Results for B</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You should not have two checkboxes with the same name, but if you have to at least give them different ids.
2. It's better to check if the `checkbox` is checked using `is(':checked')`
3. Regarding the login - check the example:

```js
var a = $(".one");
var b = $(".two");
a.hide();
b.hide();

$(".inputfield input[name='xyz']").change(function() {
  var A_is_checked = $(".inputfield input[name='xyz']:first").is(':checked');
  var B_is_checked = $(".inputfield input[name='xyz']:last").is(':checked');
  
  if (A_is_checked && B_is_checked) {
      a.show();
      b.show();
  } else if (A_is_checked) {
      a.show();
      b.hide();
  } else if (B_is_checked) {
      a.hide();
      b.show();
  } else {
    a.hide();
    b.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="inputfield">
    <label for="">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="A" id="A" />
    <label for="">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="B" id="B" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="one">Results for A</div>
<div class="one">Results for A</div>
<div class="two">Results for B</div>
```

If you can't change the markup you can select the relevant checkbox by it's value, using:

```
var A_is_checked = $("input[name='xyz'][value='A']").is(':checked');
var B_is_checked = $("input[name='xyz'][value='B']").is(':checked');
```

Or by the position in the DOM:

```
var A_is_checked = $("input[name='xyz']:first").is(':checked');
var B_is_checked = $("input[name='xyz']:last").is(':checked');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the markup. Can it be done in another way?

Comment: @Meek added this option to the answer